# ScrollTop in a dynamic tab

Tags: jquery, tabs, scrolltop

I'm using the code below to display an 'up arrow' in a tabbed container if a user scrolls down the page. Each tab has an 'up arrow'. In the original code I used .show and .hide, but that didn't work at all. And whilst searching for a solution I read scrolltop has some troubles after a display:none, so I opted for visibility:hidden.

This works great on the tab that is opened by default. However, if I navigate to the next tab, it stops working. I suspect I need to add something that binds or refreshes the scroll function. (Perhaps like the on click function in the second part of the code?)

```
/* Scroll Arrow */
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 300) {
        $("#sideAnchor").css('visibility', 'visible');

    } else {

        $("#sideAnchor").css('visibility', 'hidden');
    }
  });
});

/* Scroll Top */
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $("#content-home").on( "click", "#mainAnchor", function() {
$("#content-home").scrollTop(0);
    });
});

jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $("#sidemenu-container").on( "click", "#sideAnchor", function() {
$("html, body").scrollTop(0);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to have a lot of `jQuery(document).ready()`, it's not a good practice to do. It all does the same thing as having just one. Also, you don't need to have an 'up arrow' on each tab you can just have one, position it `fixed` on the bottom corner.

You just need to reset the scrollbar at the top when the user clicks each the tab.

```
$('tabs').click(function(){
    $(window).scrollTop(0);
});

$(window).scroll(function () {
   if ($(this).scrollTop() > 300) {
       $("#sideAnchor").css('visibility', 'visible');
   }else{
       $("#sideAnchor").css('visibility', 'hidden');
   }
});
```

You can also animate the scrolling to top, UX-wise:

```
$('up_arrow').click(function(){
    $('body, html').animate({scrollTop:0},'slow');
});
```

Check this sample [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mark_s/h7uJ4/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Mark. I thought I needed the arrow on each tab, because of the way the layout is set up. (there's a fixed div allready in that spot with dynamic content) Anyways it got me thinking and if restructured it to incorporate your fix. Much easier now. :) Also thanks for the comment about 'document ready' removed a  bunch of those. I know about the animate function, just read that it can be troublesome on a mobile. So I figured not to use is, thanks anyways!